# How to check if a special character available in url and redirect to a permanent url?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have few urls contain some special characters like below

```
www.abc.com/archive/category/コレクション-帯-袋帯
www.abc.com/archive/category/お役立ち情報
```

I want to write .htaccess to handle this redirection.

I tried this way but its not working

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\コ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\お [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I can write like this

```
RewriteRule ^archive/category/コレクション-帯締め-三分紐$ / [R=301,L]
```

but there were many urls like above with simple changes, can't repeat all urls in .htaccess file

How can i do this? Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Geshode I did not get any errors, redirection not happening as i given

Comment: Multiple RewriteCond are joined with an implicit AND (unless you specify otherwise with the `OR` flag) - so right now, you are demanding that THE_REQUEST needs to contain both `コ` and `お` at the same time, but that is not the case for either of the two example URLs you have given.

Comment: No need to use a RewriteCond for this to begin with - the RewriteRule is perfectly capable of matching against the URL path component, on its own. `RewriteRule (コ|お) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` should be enough to achieve what you want here.

Comment: ...and `THE_REQUEST` is URL-encoded (ie. %-encoded), whereas the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is not (which is why your second example "works").